# .load() is not pulling in content from html file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using the jQuery Docs and I am trying to set up a situation where the content of a modal is filled from a separate html file. All files are on the same domain, same folder. So far, the modal will launch on click, but no content is being pulled in from the html file. I'm using Zurb reveal for modal.

jQuery:

```
$('.video-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var modalUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#myModal').load('modalUrl #vidModal').reveal({
        animationspeed: 500,
        animation: 'fadeAndPop',
        dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal'
    });

    //$('.video-wrapper').children().show();
});
```

The Link

```
<a href="modal1.html" class="info-btn video-btn">
     <h2>Video</h2>
     <p>Cambridge at a glance</p>
</a>

/*Outer modal hidden on page*/
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal"></div>/*Content that is in a file named modal1.html*/
<div id="vidModal" class="reveal-modal">
    <div class="inner-modal">
        <div class="modal-head">
            <h2>Video</h2>
            <p>Cambridge at a glance</p>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-share-btns"></div>
        <div class="video-wrapper">
            <iframe id="vid" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/20800836?api=1" width="700" height="400" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /inner-modal -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code should look like this:

`$('#myModal').load(modalUrl+ ' #vidModal')`

in your code you load the url `modalUrl #vidModal` and not the url stored in `modalUrl` concatenated with  `#vidModal`

*(Updated base on comments)*

Comment: My thinking here was based off the jQuery docs which had this:

$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
When this method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded.

Comment: Technically should be `$('myModal').load(modalUrl + ' #vidModal');` so you retain the fragment selector. However, the key point is that you need to use the variable, not a string literal that just says "modalUrl" for the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem:

```
$('#myModal').load('modalUrl #vidModal')
```

`modalURl` is being included as part of the string literal.

You should do:

```
$('#myModal').load(modalUrl + ' #vidModal')
```